# Is it possible to call the constructor of a super class, two classes away from the current class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have three classes that inherit as follows:

```
Class_A  
Class_B : public Class_A  
Class_C : public Class_B
```

`Class_A` contains a constructor:

```
public: Class_A(const char *name, int kind);
```

`Class_B` does not contain that constructor.

In `Class_C` I wish to invoke the constructor of Class_A. Something like:
`Class_C(const char *name, int kind) : Class_A::Class_A(name,kind) {`}

The problem is that I cannot add an intermediate constructor to `Class_B`, because `Class_B` is generated code that regenerates every time I make clean. So I cannot make any lasting changes to `Class_B`. Needless to say, the above line of the constructor in `Class_C` gives the `error: "type 'Class_A' is not a direct base of '`Class_C`'".`

Is there a way that I may invoke the constructor of `Class_A` in the subclass `Class_C`, without requiring the same type of constructor in `Class_B`?

Comment: Can't you change the code that generates B?

Comment: Ew at all the `Class_` prefixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't change the code that generates `B`, then you are out of luck, AFAIK. But if the `A` class contains such a constructor, maybe you can get away with adding a simple member function that sets those two variables and call it from inside the `C` constructor? May not be as efficient as it gets, but atleast it works.

Comment: Great idea! I've implemented Class_C's constructor as you advised and it works perfectly. I also had some issues with the copy constructor requiring the name constructor, but I think I've hacked my way around this with you advice. I just hope that there isn't some other super class, whose initialization I'm ignoring.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make the base class a virtual base class you can do this, as virtual bases must always uninitialized in the outermost constructor directly.  If you can't change how ClassB inherits from A you can always do this:

```
RealClassA
ClassA : public virtual RealClassA
ClassB : public ClassA
ClassC : public ClassB
```

Then in the ClassC constructor you can call `RealClassA(...)` directly.

Usually this *feature* of virtual inheritence is a real pain, but it might actually help you here.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably stuffed (assuming you can't change class B's generation), but **if** there happen to be any constructors for B that are templates, then you can specialise one (for a unique dummy class) and create your own custom constructor with whatever base-class-A construction you feel like....

Otherwise, while less efficient, the obvious, safe, clean approach is to use A's `operator=` (if any) to get the value you want into it...

```
C c;
c = A(x, y);
```

If those fields of A can only be set at construction time, then it's a harder problem....

(Stepping momentarily and deeply into the dreaded land of Undefined Behaviour, you could invoke A's destructor then placement `new` it, but A's lifespan is meant to span Bs and Cs.  Practically, the obvious risk is that A created something like a heap-allocated value that B or C already holds a pointer to and may try to use after A destructor releases it....)

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility would be for `Class_B` to inherit virtually from
`Class_A`; in that case, the constructor for `Class_A` would be called
from the most derived class.  But since this would also involve changing
the code generator, or the input to the code generator, you might as
well change it to add the additional constructor to `Class_B`.

If you really can't change the code generator or its input in a way that
would cause it to generate the additional constructor, but you can
change `Class_A` and `Class_C`, then there are two possible solutions:

The simplest is simply to use deferred initialization; add a function to
`Class_A` which takes the appropriate parameters, and does the
initialization after the constructor has finished.  While the simplest,
this method can only be used if `Class_A` can be made to support default
construction as well, and if all of the members of `Class_A` support
assignment, with semantics such that default construction followed
by assignment has the same result as construction using the arguments
you give (i.e. no reference members, no noncopiable members, no
`const` members, etc.).

Alternatively, you can put all of the functionality (or at least the
data members) of `Class_A` in a separate class, and have `Class_A`
derive from this class virtually.  `Class_C` will then call the
constructor of this new class.

Answer (score 0):

If B is generated, then change the generator, otherwise you're doomed.

Depending on what B is doing, might be a solution to change your design to have C derivation from A and B directly (if A is your container class and B a processing class). Doing this, might require you to template B. If B needs to act on A members, you can still give an A pointer to B constructor...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constructor for `Class_B`, which has the same signature as ctor of `Class_A`, and then let `Class_C` call that in ctor.

Besides, a class ctor initialization list could not set values for members in base class (no matter they are `private` `protected` or `public`). You must use the base class' ctor to set them.

Answer (score 0):

By language one cannot access non-immediate base constructors.

By the way, If `Class_A` constructor signature is,

```
Class_A(const char *name, int kind);
```

then, `Class_B` should have some constructor which will entertain the `Class_A` constructor of the given type. Otherwise it will give compiler error.

The only way to get rid of that error is to provide default arguments to `Class_A::Class_A(...)`.

Comment: @Xeo, In question OP has mentioned: `Class_B` does not contain that constructor.